# Selenium XPath Difference in selector

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

What is the difference between the 2 XPaths below ?

> By.xpath("./a[text()='" + personName + "']")
>
> By.xpath("//a[text()='" + personName + "']")

Basically difference between using

> ./

and

> //

Answer (score 3):

```
./a
```

Returns all `<a>` elements that are **direct children** of **current context** node. This is relative path.

```
//a
```

Returns all `<a>` elements at **any level depth** within **the root** node. Without leading point (`.`), `/` and `//` axes are considered absolute.